# boost interprocess shared memory: how to have multiple different shared memory on same machine

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following two processes that communicate with shared memory. How should I modify these so that I can run two copies of each on the same machine without them interfering with each other?  i.e. p1 shares memory only with p2, and p1.1 shares memory only with p2.1

Thanks!

process 1:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    //use old shared memory if exists else create a new one
    shared_memory_object shm(open_or_create, "shared_memory", read_write);
    //set the size of the memory object
    shm.truncate(sizeof(shared_memory_buffer));
    //map the whole shared memory in this process
    mapped_region region(shm,read_write);
    //get the region address
    void * addr = region.get_address();
    //create a shared memory buffer in memory
    shared_memory_buffer *data = new (addr) shared_memory_buffer;
    while(true){
            //wait until the written number gets executed
            data->writer.wait();
            //print the square root of the original value
            std::cout << "Square Root: " << data->value << "\n";
            //create the original value
            data->value = atoi(argv[1]); //rand() % 100 + 1;
            sleep(1);
            //reader can execute written number
            data->writer.post();
            sleep(rand()%5 +1);
    }
    return 0;
```

}

process2:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //create a shared memory object.
    shared_memory_object shm(open_only, "shared_memory",read_write);
    //Map the whole shared memory in this process
    mapped_region region(shm,read_write);
    //get the region address
    void * addr = region.get_address();
    //Obtain the shared structure
    shared_memory_buffer * data = static_cast<shared_memory_buffer *>(addr);
    while(true){
            //wait until a number gets available
            data->writer.wait();
            //print the original value
            std::cout << "Original Value: " << data->value << "\n";
            //create the sqrt of the original value
            data->value = atoi(argv[1]); //sqrt(data->value);
            //sleep(1);
            //writer can print sqrt
            data->writer.post();
            sleep(rand()%5 +1);
    }
    return 0;
```

}

both processes use this struct:

```
struct shared_memory_buffer {
    //writer initialized with one to start
    //reader have to wait
    shared_memory_buffer(): writer(1), reader(1), value(0){}

    interprocess_semaphore writer, reader;

    float value;
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a distinct name for your shared memory realm (I.e. instead of "shared_memory")

Including a GUID is common practice.